# How can I get the full test output from mocha with spec?

Tags: npm, mocha.js, specifications

I've just installed mocha and am using fairly basic settings to run 2 tests, but it won't output all the results.

I am expecting to see:

```
foo
  bar
    √ does thing
  baz
    √ does other thing
```

but I am only seeing the first 2-4 lines (varies with no discernible pattern). It seems there's some sort of time-dependent element here, but I have no idea how to approach fixing it.

- The environment is cygwin under Windows 8.
- I am running mocha by running `npm test`.
- My test command in package.json is `mocha test/*.js -R spec`.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck finding an answer?
I'm on a different OS and your config looks good.
Works in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha -R spec"
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a long time, but I don't remember ever finding a fix for it.